# Retrieve count for each id based on a filter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe the question is trivial but I cannot figure out! 
I have a table like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Val_1 | Val_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  |   0   |   1   |
| 2  |   0   |   0   |
| 3  |   1   |   0   |
| 1  |   0   |   1   |
| 2  |   1   |   0   |
| 4  |   0   |   0   |
```

The ID field is not unique (I have another key in the table).
What I  would like to retrieve is a count for each ID where ((Val_1 > 0) OR (Val_  > 0)):

```
+----+-------+
| ID | count |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   2   |
| 2  |   1   |
| 3  |   1   |
| 4  |   0   |
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, 
       sum(Val_1 > 0 OR Val_ > 0) as count
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: OMG!! It was so simple!! Thanks a lot! I have to study again an SQL book!!